# How can I use CallKit to take video chat calls

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, videochat

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that implements video chat. For now, a video call is made by sending push notifications using UIKit, and is answered by touching the push notification. I would like to use a native iOS telephony feature, that would let the user make a real phone ringing etc. I heard that it could be done using Callkit, but I can't find any example or explanation on how this can be done. Or maybe there is some way other than Callkit? Basically, answering the call (like with a common phone call) should replace touching the notification.

Comment: "would like to use a native android telephony" - CallKit is an iOS API.  It's really unclear what you are asking for. There are fairly extensive native and Xamarin documentation on CallKit.  You also haven't provided any detail on how you've implemented video chat.  I would start by looking at the vendor docs for whatever tool you are using and see if they support CallKit integration.

Comment: @Jason I think what I need is this: when a push notification arrives, the phone would ring, and when the user answers the call, then an appropriate action would happen. Basically, answering the call (like with a common phone call) should replace touching the notification. With android it was a type, sorry. Will fix.